# How to get Sku, name, and image in magento2 in phtml file

Tags: magento2

I don't know how to implement this task. I want to get product name, SKU, and image in magento2. Can you please help me?

Comment: where to get product name, SKU, and image on custome module.

Comment: I want in the custom link which is near to add to cart button